# Python で Excel セル内に変数内の数字は挿入できない？

Tags: python, excel

変数gk2に29が入っており、これをExcelのA60に挿入したいです。

```
sheet = wb['HMR']
sheet['A60'] = '="6F"&gk2&"人"'
```

"6F 29人" と表示したいのですが、上記のコードで実行すると "6F 人" と表示されます。
セルに挿入する際に変数の値は挿入できないものなのでしょうか？
何かいい方法があれば、教えていただけないでしょうか？[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「"6F 人"と表示される」のはJupyterの中ですか？ それとも変更したファイルをEXCELで開いた時ですか？ ちなみに`'="6F"&gk2&"人"'`をセルに入れるのはEXCELシート上の`GK2`セルの内容を参照・連結して表示するマクロ(式？)を入力しているように見えます。`gk2`変数はPythonスクリプト上にしか存在しないのでEXCELでファイルを開いても参照できません。`=`とか`&`とかEXCELの機能を使う文字列ではなく、`"6F 29人"`という文字列をPython(Jupyter)上で作成して、それをそのままセルに代入すれば良いのでは？ あるいは`sheet['GK2'] = gk2`という行を追加してEXCELシート上の`GK2`セルに該当の内容を代入しておくとか？

Answer (score 1):

コメントの通り、GK2セルの値を取りに行くエクセル関数が記述されているようです。
サンプルコードのように、pythonの文字列へ`gk2`変数を代入して動作を確認してください。

**サンプルコード**

```
gk2 = 29
print('="6F"&gk2&"人"')          # GK2 セルの値を代入
print('="6F' + str(gk2) + '人"') # 文字列を + 記号で連結
print(f'="6F{gk2}人"')           # フォーマット文字列でgk2変数を展開 (python 3.6 以降利用可能)

# sheet['A60'] = f'6F{gk2}人'    # セルに`gk2`変数を代入した文字列を設定する(「="6F29人"」のようなエクセル関数化は不要)
```

**実行結果**

```
="6F"&gk2&"人" 
="6F29人" 
="6F29人"
```